# Customising Simple Form Collection_Select

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I've got this simple form and I want to be able to style the dropdown menu with css.

The `input_html: { class: "form-dropdown" }` isn't changing the style. How am I able to properly add a class to the simple form `collection_select` to style it in css, or is there any other way I can style the dropdown menu?

This is my simple form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @document do |f| %>

    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {promt: "Choose a category" }, input_html: { class: "form-dropdown" } %>

    <%= f.input :title, label: "Title", label_html: { class: 'form-input' } %>

    <%= f.input :pdf, label: "Upload document:" %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leave off  `input_html:` thats why it is not working. define it like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {promt: "Choose a category" }, { class: "form-dropdown" } %>
```

or

```
 <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, promt: "Choose a category", class: "form-dropdown" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :category_id, category_select_options, {prompt: "---Select Category---"}, required: :required, class: "form-control" %>

#
# In Appication Helper
#

def category_select_options
  Category.all.map{|c| [c.name,c.id] }
end
```